# Vedarama's historical evidence in Hinduism

Tags: scripture, puranas, rama

Any Hindu scriptures giving evidence of Vedarama? The qualities, the traits he perceived and what good qualities we should learn from Vedarama?

Comment: One of the Vishnu subavatar--like tirupathi venkatachalapathi. Now you came to know about my questions which will be ironical.

Comment: I bought the book day before--have to read--will provide the answer in a shortwhile. I  hope am increasing the knowledge of this site members by asking such questions and providing answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Paramathma is veda vethyan.In Ramavatar  Lord Rama followed vedas and showed the human dharma to the world amidst blessings. When all the devathas prayed thru veda manthiras, Paramathama told that I will take birth as son  to  King Dasaratha and rule the world as per directionsof Vedas. Hence he is called Veda Reman.

**Source**: Veda Raman by Mukkur Lakshmi Narasimhachar of Vanathi Publications.